# PowerBuilder - Pass a NonVisualObject as a function argument

Tags: powerbuilder

PowerBuilder 10.5

Apparently, in a function I cannot pass an argument of the base type *NonVisualObject*.  I can pass a argument that is of type *UserObject*, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I created a simple *NonVisualObject* as means of a DTO (Data-Transfer-Object) to pass simple data to my function.

Any ideas on how to pass a type of *NonVisualObject* to my function?

Comment: I have tested that nothing should prevent you from passing nvo as function argument. Can you give more details on your problem? Do you have a compiler error message, or an arror at runtime?

Comment: Ditto to what Seki said. Sure what you're trying to pass is a NonVisualObject and not a structure or something else? When you Edit Source the object, what does it say after the first "from"?  And if it names one of your objects, what does *it's* "from" say? (Recurse until you find a system object type.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you are looking in the dropdown list for the argument type? You can type any valid class name in those boxes.
2. If you declare the parameter as `nonvisualobject` the function won't have access to any of the properties you added to your object*. You should declare the parameter as the class name you gave your NonVisualObject (see #1).

*It's possible to cast the argument to the correct type within the function but you should have a very good reason to pass an ancestor and cast to a descendant. Doing so safely is an advanced technique.

Comment: Yes, embarrassingly enough I thought i could ONLY pick a type from the dropdown list.  I ended up just specifying the exact type.  Give me a break, PB (and it's IDE) isn't my specialty :)

Comment: Oh, I've run into folks that have been using PB for years and never knew this. Seriously, who's going to pour over every line in the PB User's  Guide? Certainly I've dissected the DataWindow documentation, but it's obvious how to work the function painter.